# Change links name and href after it's been clicked

Tags: javascript, php, href

I have the following link:

```
<span class="hds-icon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true"><!-- --></span>  <a href="<?=$this->recordLink()->getActionUrl($this->driver, 'Save')?>" data-lightbox class="save-record" data-id="<?=$this->escapeHtmlAttr($this->driver->getUniqueId()) ?>"><?=$this->transEsc('Add to favorites')?></a><br/>
        <br/>
```

Now I want to change the text "add to favorites" to "allready added to favorites" after the link has been clicked.
I guess a onclick-function would not work as it would redirect, to the new page before the link would be clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop default behaviour of link using `event.preventDefault()`

But also you have to send request to target page using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) for performing actual functions that are related to database.

```js
document.querySelector("a").onclick = function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  this.innerHTML = "Already Added to Favorites";
  var href = this.getAttribute("href");
  //$.ajax({url : href ,...});
};
```

```html
<a href = "/">Add to favorites</a>
```